# Is an HTTP client allowed to send multiple headers with the same name?

Tags: http

I'm aware that HTTP servers can send headers with duplicate keys (at least `Set-Cookie` comes to mind), but is there a plausible reason for clients to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RFC 7230 does allow for duplicate headers under some circumstances. From [section 3.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2):

> A sender MUST NOT generate multiple header fields with the same field
> name in a message unless either the entire field value for that
> header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]
> or the header field is a well-known exception (as noted below).

A recipient MAY combine multiple header fields with the same field
name into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the
semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field value to
the combined field value in order, separated by a comma.

One somewhat "plausible" scenario comes to mind: When the HTTP request is passing through a proxy, the proxy might simply tack on another header (say, an `X-Forwarded-For`, or an extra `Accept-Encoding`), rather than determine if a header already exists, then parse and modify it accordingly.

Technically, any client is "allowed" to send multiple headers with the same name, so long as it meets the requirements in RFC 7230 above.

Comment: This means that client is not allowed to send multiple headers with the same name but is required to combine multiple values into a comma separated list sent in 1 header field. The only exception stated by RFC 7230 seems to be the "Set-Cookie" header.

Comment: @user3625699 Set-Cookie is one of the two exceptions. The other is "the entire field value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]". So it's allowed, under those 2 circumstances.

Comment: The ""the entire field value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list" case means in practise that 1 header is placed in the HTTP request but it contains multiple values inside that 1 header.

Comment: That's correct, In the case where the normative form of a header is a single header with comma-separated values, it is permissible instead to have multiple headers that use the same name. It can be freely converted into a single, comma-separated header, but there is no requirement to do so. This is one of the 2 cases that appear immediately after the word "unless" in the portion of RFC7230 I quoted in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

a) It might be easier when multiple pieces of code are involved,

b) It can be unavoidable for certain fields such as Set-Cookie (see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#rfc.section.3.2.2.p.4).